# Logarithms and exponential decay

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

The table describes the cooling of a cup of coffee as it sits on your teacher’s desk in the math office. Time (min) $0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20$ Temperature (celsius) $55, 47, 40, 34, 29, 25$

a) Calculate $a$, the cooling factor (rate at which the coffee cools per minute) of the coffee. Round your answer to two decimal places.

b) Determine an equation for $y$, the temperature of the coffee in degrees Celsius after $t$ minutes.

c) Is your model a good predictor of the temperature of the coffee at any point in time? Explain.

Comment: I think I am using y=c(x)^x here, but i'm not sure if this is correct

Comment: y=c(a)^x** sorry about the typo

Comment: No, I think you use $a(1-r)^t$

Comment: Really?  Because I completed a question recently with similar principles that used y=c(a)^x where c is the initial amount, a is the amount it grows or decays and x is the interval which in this case is time in minutes.  I got the correct answer on that question to.

Comment: Ok. No problem. We can go form here

Comment: Okay , well if I used that formula how would I go about doing this then?  You can find that it's second differences in the table havev a constant of -1.  The temperatures decrease rate gets smaller and smaller by -1 every 4 minutes. But i'm thinking there is any easier way to do this that I'm just not thinking of

Comment: I will write an answer hang on.

Comment: ok. Take your time.

Comment: I have finished. I left c) for you to do. If you believe that you are satisfied, mark this answer as "correct" to show that this question is finalized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had decided to solve this problem using $y=i(1-a)^t$ to solve this problem, where $y$ is the final amount, $i$ is the initial amount, $a$ is the rate of decrease or "cooling factor" in this case, and $t$ is the number of time periods. you will see why I used this formula in a little bit.

a) To solve for $a$, we can input some values from the table to fill in the variables for $i$, $y$ and $t$:

$y=47,$
$i=55,$
$t=4,$

$$47=55(1-a)^4.$$

Now from this, we can solve for $a$ to find the cooling factor:

$$\frac{47}{55}=(1-a)^4$$

$$\sqrt[4]{\frac{47}{55}}=1-a$$
$$-a=\sqrt[4]{\frac{47}{55}}-1$$
$$\sqrt[4]{\frac{47}{55}}\approx0.961$$ 
$$0.961-1=-0.039$$

So from this, $-a=-0.039$. We must transfer the negative sign and we get $a=0.039$. But since we are rounding to the "second decimal place, we get $\boxed{a=0.04}$.

b) Since we have found the value for $a$, We can develop our equation:

$$\boxed{y=55(1-0.04)^t=55(0.96)^t}.$$

c) From what I have provided you with, I think you will be able to answer this question.

Comment: hmm, i'm not sure how you got the 0.04.  I input it into my calculator and I get a different answer.  Could you explain the last step please?

Comment: $$\sqrt[4]{\frac{47}{55}}\approx0.961$$ $$0.961-1=-0.039$$ So from this, $-a=-0.039$. We must transfer the negative sign and we get $a=0.039$. But since we are rounding to the "second decimal place, we get $\boxed{a=0.04}$.

Comment: Oh okay you rounded the number, I see that now.  Thanks for clearing that up

Comment: @user209097 No prob. I have added it into my answer. You can check my answer off to signal that this question is finalized. :)

Comment: That's the check mark under the arrows on the left side of the answer yes?  Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Yes. No problem. Anytime! :)